# F# string concatenation hangs an async computation

Tags: f#

Here is a basic async computation but I cannot explain the behaviour and it drives me crazy!

```
let noConcatStr = "42"
let concatStr = "4" + "2"

let asyncConcat =
    async {
        printfn "before"
        do! Async.Sleep 1000
        printfn "%s" concatStr
        printfn "after"
    }

let run = asyncConcat |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This trivial async code never returns and remains hung! If I switch `concaStr` with `noConcatStr`, the code returns as expected after 1s sleep.

There is certainly a rationale behind that behaviour that is due to `System.String.Concat` but I really cannot find it.

Insights much appreciated.

Comment: Your concatenation doesn't happen inside the async workflow.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I got that... but why not? Any link to make me understand?

Comment: That's just how the language works. Values are evaluated when they are declared, not when they are accessed.

Comment: [I can't replicate this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e47FGp). Maybe some other bit of context is missing?

Comment: Same here, [it works](https://repl.it/repls/ClearPeriodicMiddleware#main.fs). @MathieuFrançois can you try posting a reproducible example, where it hangs?